# Use collection with json_decode object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-collection

I'm having a data set which is coming through request in my `Laravel 6` application, I want to convert this to collection but it is not working out:

```
$request_status = json_decode($request->status);

$data = collect($request_status)->pluck('id');

dd($data);
```

This is giving me output of `null`;

When I do `dd($request->status)`:

```
"[{"id":3,"type":"Awarded","name":"Awarded"}]"
```

No change happens in the data, if I do `dd($data)` I get:

```
Collection {#791 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => null
  ]
}
```

I tried doing `json_decode($request->status, true)` but no luck.

Comment: `"[{"id":3,"type":"Awarded","name":"Awarded"}]"` will be error. Are you sure this is the value of `$request->status`?

Comment: Try to change `'[{"id":3,"type":"Awarded","name":"Awarded"}]'`, it can run normally.

Comment: what you are getting for `gettype($request)` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you dd $request_status it returns

```
"[{"id":3,"type":"Awarded","name":"Awarded"}]"
```

as a string? Makes sense that the pluck('id') doesn't work then. If so, make sure that returns an array and it'll work.

When I try

```
$request_status = json_decode('[{"id":3,"type":"Awarded","name":"Awarded"}]');

$data = collect($request_status)->pluck('id');

dd($data);
```

it returns

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection^ {#631
  #items: array:1 [
    0 => 3
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about correctness but, I have tried something

```
$request_status = json_decode($request->status,1);

$data = collect([$request_status])->pluck('id')->first();

dd($data);
```